# How do you configure grep to act more like ack?

Tags: grep, ack

How would you get grep to exclude the files that ack excludes (temp files and version control directories) without typing out the exclude patterns?

As [described here](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/default-grep-options/), you could use GREP_OPTIONS, but then you run into the [problems here](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/24141/): scripts that use grep without clearing GREP_OPTIONS will break.

What is the better way? An alias? Or another script that wraps grep?

*While the obvious answer is `alias grep="ack -a"`, I'm academically interested in how to solve this problem without using ack.*

Comment: Aside: ack 2.0 does away with the `-a` and `-u` flags. The default in 2.0 is to select all text files for searching, regardless of filetype.

Comment: Also, note that `ack -a` is still not equivalent to `grep`, because ack will still ignore certain directories and files.  `-a` means "all file types", not "all files".

Comment: As of grep 2.20, GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grep-commit/2014-09/msg00007.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to use an alias to restrict the use of my smart options to my interactive inputs (and not other people's scripts). This is the grep-relevant snippet from my bash_aliases:

```
SMART_GREP_OPTIONS=

# Ensure colors are supported.
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    SMART_GREP_OPTIONS=' --color=auto'
fi


# Make grep more like ack.
#   Ignore binary files.
SMART_GREP_OPTIONS="$SMART_GREP_OPTIONS --binary-files=without-match"
# Check for exclude-dir to prevent invalid options in older versions of grep.
# Assume if we have exclude-dir, that we have exclude.
if /bin/grep --help | /bin/grep -- --exclude-dir &>/dev/null; then
    # Ignore version control folders.
    for PATTERN in .cvs .git .hg .svn; do
        SMART_GREP_OPTIONS="$SMART_GREP_OPTIONS --exclude-dir=$PATTERN"
    done
    # Ignore temp files.
    for PATTERN in *.swp; do
        SMART_GREP_OPTIONS="$SMART_GREP_OPTIONS --exclude=$PATTERN"
    done
fi
# This alias may override ghostscript. That's not a problem for me.
alias gs='grep $SMART_GREP_OPTIONS'
```

I do most of my grepping from vim and use [vim-searchsavvy](https://github.com/idbrise/vim-searchsavvy) to setup similar options (I don't use my alias from vim).